# What is the diffrence between .jpg and .j2k format?

Tags: image, jpeg

I need to do conformance tests of JPEG decoder. The streams available in ITUS are .j2k for jpeg2000 format. What is the standard used in .jpg format? How do they differ in structure? How can I view the J2k files?

Answer (score 1):

[JPEG 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) is a completely different file format from JPEG (which is usually what `.jpg` files are). The Wikipedia article I linked gives a list of compatible software.